# I want to draw a graph using a weighted Adjacency matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks, homework

I have a weighted adjacency matrix as follows:

```
myAdjacencyMatrix = {{0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 8, 0, 0, 3, 4},
  {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 16, 5, 3, 0, 6, 1},
  {2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0},
  {5, 3, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
  {1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 2, 6, 10, 2, 4},
  {0, 11, 3, 0, 1, 0, 8, 3, 1, 3, 3},
  {2, 4, 1, 7, 6, 7, 0, 6, 0, 8, 2},
  {1, 2, 1, 3, 8, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 0, 6, 4},
  {0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 2, 6, 0, 4},
  {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0}}
```

I want to draw a graph with 11 nodes and the edges weighted as described above. If this is impossible, then I will settle for making a graph with the non-weighted adjacency matrix.

If you could just give me the simple code as I am new to mathematica and am working on a tight schedule.

Comment: `WeightedAdjacencyGraph[Range[11], myAdjacencyMatrix]` should do it

Comment: If you are really working on a tight schedule, I seriously suggest trying with another language. Mathematica has a steep learning curve and isn't appropriate for rush learning

Comment: How do you want the weights to modify the drawing of the graph?

Comment: mmm ... re reading your questions so far, your "tight schedule" seems dangerously near a "homework delivery deadline"

Comment: Not homework, just project work which needs to be completed. 

@Szabolcs - I dont mind if the weights are just written, otherwise the weight of the line would be effective.

Comment: @belisarius Do you mean Mathematica has a shallow learning curve, assuming time on x-axis and amount learnt on y  ? :)

Comment: @image_doctor Shallower if you plot "amount studied" vs. "% still not learnt", in any scale

Comment: @image_doctor: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/6226/1635

Answer (score 12):

I'm not too good at graphs, but this seems straightforward.

```
myAdjacencyMatrix =
{{0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 8, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2},
 {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 16, 5, 3, 0, 6, 1},
 {2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0},
 {5, 3, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
 {1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 2, 6, 10, 2, 4},
 {0, 11, 3, 0, 1, 0, 8, 3, 1, 3, 3},
 {2, 4, 1, 7, 6, 7, 0, 6, 0, 8, 2},
 {1, 2, 1, 3, 8, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 0, 6, 4},
 {0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 2, 6, 0, 4},
 {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0}} /. 0 -> Infinity
```

(I added an extra 2 to your first row.) Belisarius proposes the `0 -> Infinity` to remove 0 weights.

A graph:

```
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[myAdjacencyMatrix, 
     VertexLabels -> "Name",
     EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
     EdgeShapeFunction -> f, 
     VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 18]];
```

Then an edge function:

```
f[pts_List, e_] := 
 Block[{s = 0.015, weight = PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeWeight]},
  {Arrowheads[{{s, 0.1}, {s, 0.9}}], 
   AbsoluteThickness[weight * 1.5], 
   Arrow[pts]}]
```

Then draw the graph:

```
Show[g]
```

[image: graph]

Still looks too messy to be really useful.

By the way, is it correct to make edge rendering function refer to the graph, and the graph function to call the edge rendering function? Seems a bit circular to me...

### Update - "Is there anyway to move the nodes?"

I found out that it's straightforward to control the positions of the nodes in advance. You have to create a list of coordinates - in this case 11 are needed - and provide them to the `VertexCoordinates` option. For example, here is a set of 11 points, arranged in two layers, of four and six points, around a central point:

```
vertices = 
  Join[
   {{0, 0}},
   Table[{4 Cos[a], 4 Sin[a]}, {a, Pi/4, 2  Pi, Pi/2}],
   Table[{7 Cos[a], 7 Sin[a]}, {a, 0, 5 Pi/3, Pi/3}]
  ];
```

Then create the graph using the `VertexCoordinates -> vertices`:

[image: graph moved vertices]

Comment: To get the "simplified" graph do just `myAdjacencyMatrix  /. 0 -> Infinity`

Comment: @belisarius That works well, thanks! Updated.

Comment: Brilliant thankyou. Tried to upvote but wasnt allowed. Is there anyway to move the nodes into a customised format?

Comment: Right-click gives some alternatives, but it's complicated stuff...

Comment: @Ryan I don't think you have enough reputation to upvote...

Comment: @Ryan as a new user you do not yet have the [voting privilege](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) but you can still [Accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the entries of `myAdjacencyMatrix` directly to set the`EdgeStyle`s:

```
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[myAdjacencyMatrix /. 0 -> Infinity, 
 GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding", 
 EdgeStyle -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> AbsoluteThickness[ myAdjacencyMatrix[[i, j]]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), it's a bit simpler.

```
myAdjacencyMatrix =
{{0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 8, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2},
 {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 16, 5, 3, 0, 6, 1},
 {2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0},
 {5, 3, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
 {1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 2, 6, 10, 2, 4},
 {0, 11, 3, 0, 1, 0, 8, 3, 1, 3, 3},
 {2, 4, 1, 7, 6, 7, 0, 6, 0, 8, 2},
 {1, 2, 1, 3, 8, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 0, 6, 4},
 {0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 2, 6, 0, 4},
 {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0}};

IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[myAdjacencyMatrix,
    GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Large],
    ImageSize -> Large] // 
  IGEdgeMap[AbsoluteThickness, EdgeStyle -> IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]]
```

[image]

`IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` saves you the trouble of having to replace zeros with infinities and `IGEdgeMap` makes it easy to style based on weight.